# Optimizing Portfolio With Bounds on Weights and Costs

Tags: optimization, matlab, finance, portfolio

I wish to create efficient frontiers for portfolios with bounds on both weights and costs. The following code provides the frontiers for portfolios in which the underlying assets are bounded with minimum and maximum weights. How do I add to this a secondary constraint in which the combined annual charges of the underlying assets do not exceed a maximum? Assume each asset has an annual cost which is applied as a percentage. As such the combined weights*charges should not exceed x%.

```
    lb=Bounds(:,1);
ub=Bounds(:,2);

P = Portfolio('AssetList', AssetList,'LowerBound', lb, 'UpperBound', ub, 'Budget', 1);
P = P.estimateAssetMoments(AssetReturns);
[Passetmean, Passetcovar] = P.getAssetMoments;


Correlations=corrcoef(AssetReturns);

% Estimate Frontier

pwgt = P.estimateFrontier(20);

[prsk, pret] = P.estimatePortMoments(pwgt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mary,

having entered another set of constraint principles into the model, kindly notice, that the modified efficient frontier problem is out of the grounds of a guaranteed convex-optimisation problem.

Thus one may forget about a comfort of all the popular **`fmicg()`**, l-bgfs et al solvers.

This will not simply have a SLOC one-liner to get answer(s) out of the box.

Non-linear problems will require  ( the wilder, the more ... ) you to assemble another optimisation function, be it either

- a **brute-force** based scanner,

  with a fully orthogonal mesh scanned, with "utility function" defined so that, as the given requirement states, it incorporates also the add-on cost-of-beholding a Portfolio item

or

- a **genetic-algorithm** based approach,

  in a belief, the brute-force one might become as time-extensive as to cease to be a feasible approach and a GA-evolution may yield acceptable sub-optimal (local optima) outputs